# Why testing Android application takes long to load on my device or emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-emulator, android-testing

As am new to Android world, I am wandering why when I load the application to my device it takes so long to load, even some times up to 3 or 5 minute. also the emulator it takes much longer than that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Emulator may take a long time to load, but loading on device usually takes only a few seconds.

Could you give more details?

Comment: not quite sure what kind of details, but yeah when i start using the device it was taking like few second but now it take so long, which time consuming. not sure what kind of details, but the device is
toshiba AT300SE, Android version 4.1.1. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to configure the Run?:   Run ---> Run Configurations ---> Target

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Host GPU in emulation option. Also, put a small size for internal storage (say 200 MB). I did a hit and trial on emulation options and this setting worked for me.